# How to delay jquery functions

Tags: queue, delay

I've got a function:

```
            (function(jQuery) {
jQuery.fn.przelicz = function() {
return this.each(function() {


     var wysokosc = jQuery(window).height() * 0.554;
     jQuery(this).find("img").height(wysokosc);
            jQuery(this).height(wysokosc);
});

};
})(jQuery);
```

I wish that this function will be run with 300ms delay. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative using jquery api can be found here  http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard JavaScript `setTimeout()` function to run a function after a delay.

```
setTimeout(jQuery.fn.przelicz, 300);
```